# i want use Android default back button in kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am a really beginner of Kivy, Python.
i am trying to make android app and 
i want use Android dafault back button.

these are what i want.

First, Press the Back button on TS2 to go to TS1.

Second, Press the Back button on TS1 to end the application.

It is easy to make button in Screen, but that is not what i want.
I am trying to find way to use Android smartphone's dafault backbutton key in python, but i can't find it. can someone explain with this code below? Thank you for you kindness in advance.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class TS1(Screen):
    pass

class TS2(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

pt = Builder.load_file("test.kv")

class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return pt

testApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition
#:import Label kivy.uix.button.Label

ScreenManagement:
    transition: SlideTransition(direction='left')
    TS1:
    TS2:
    TS3:

<TS1>:
    name: 'TS1'
    Button:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'ts2.png'
        on_release:
            app.root.current = 'TS2'

<TS2>:
    name: 'TS2'
    Button:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'ts2.png'
        on_release:
            app.root.current = 'TS3'

<TS3>:
    name: 'TS3'
    Button:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'ts2.png'
```

Comment: You did not upload test.kv..

Comment: @embryo sry.. i just upload it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The android `back` key is the same as the keyboard's `Esc`

First you have to bind a function (e.g. `on_key`) to the key-presses.

`from kivy.core.window import Window
    Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.on_key)`

Then you have to use the `on_key` function like this:

`def on_key(self, window, key, *args):
    if key == 27:  # the esc key
        if self.ids.screens.current_screen.name == "Some name":
            # do something`

Full working code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window


class TS1(Screen):
    pass


class TS2(Screen):
    pass


class TS3(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.on_key)

    def on_key(self, window, key, *args):
        if key == 27:  # the esc key
            if self.current_screen.name == "TS1":
                return False  # exit the app from this page
            elif self.current_screen.name == "TS2":
                self.current = "TS1"
                return True  # do not exit the app
            elif self.current_screen.name == "TS3":
                self.current = "TS2"
                return True  # do not exit the app


pt = Builder.load_file("test.kv")


class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return pt


testApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: SlideTransition(direction='left')
    TS1:
    TS2:
    TS3:

<TS1>:
    name: 'TS1'
    Button:
        text: "Button 1"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = 'TS2'

<TS2>:
    name: 'TS2'
    Button:
        text: "Button 2"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = 'TS3'

<TS3>:
    name: 'TS3'
    Button:
        text: "Button 3"
```

Comment: could you write example with my `test.py`? i am really confusing use your answer. it will be really helpful to me to understand their correlation..

Comment: thank you for your kindness and sry about my mistakes...! This is real helped me a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it simply on by pressing ONBACK press for native method as mentioned below.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
     {

       }
```

*Happy Learning*

Comment: i don't get it ..is not it a Java language? and also can u tell me what is a native method?